# Session Not Working Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, session

My session values get reset once page is redirected.

I am aware of the `session.abandon()` and all. It is not only in one project, in all projects. it was working fine earlier, today only I am getting this issue in my Visual Studio 2008 as well as 2012. I tried switching the session mode between `inProc` and `State Server`. (I even started the asp.net state server service before doing it). even tried restarting the system.

Can you please tell me what could be the issue and how to fix this?

Comment: A specific redirect, or any? Do you use a hostname when redirecting (different from where you started from)? Did anything change between yesterday and today?

Comment: Not between domains. Its a simple redirect between two of my pages, it is working in another system. the problem is only with my VS. Even I haven't configured IIS in my machine